# $http get parameters does not work

Tags: javascript, angularjs, http, angular-http

Does anyone know why this does not work?

```
$http
    .get('accept.php', {
        source: link,
        category_id: category
    })
    .success(function (data, status) {
        $scope.info_show = data
    });
```

and this does work:

```
$http
    .get('accept.php?source=' + link + '&category_id=' + category)
    .success(function (data, status) {
        $scope.info_show = data
    });
```

Answer (score 192, accepted):

The 2nd parameter in the `get` call is a config object. You want something like this:

```
$http
    .get('accept.php', {
        params: {
            source: link,
            category_id: category
        }
     })
     .success(function (data,status) {
          $scope.info_show = data
     });
```

See the **Arguments** section of http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$http for more detail

Comment: Note, using `params` as above also resolves the problem of GET requests not using `data`. AngularJS will not sort this out itself as jQuery does. (I don't think that's a good or bad thing, just different and may trip people up).

Comment: I am getting undefined for my key value properties inside of the params object.  Should this be different in a service?

Comment: Also, when the `params` object is empty, or all its properties are `null` or `undefined`, nothing will be added to the query string.

Answer (score 3):

From [`$http.get` docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#get), the second parameter is a configuration object:

> #### `get(url, [config]);`
>
> Shortcut method to perform `GET` request.

You may change your code to:

```
$http.get('accept.php', {
    params: {
        source: link, 
        category_id: category
    }
});
```

Or:

```
$http({
    url: 'accept.php', 
    method: 'GET',
    params: { 
        source: link, 
        category_id: category
    }
});
```

---

As a side note, since **Angular 1.6**: `.success` [should not be used anymore](http://www.codelord.net/2015/05/25/dont-use-%24https-success/), use `.then` instead:

```
$http.get('/url', config).then(successCallback, errorCallback);
```