# How to query an API via URL using AngularJS SPA and a FORM with filters and return a value

Tags: angularjs

I have the following API URL (https://my.ncarb.org/Public/api/certification/search?pageSize=100&page=0&lastName=&firstName=&city=&stateCode=&countryCode=&orderBy=name) and I want to query it (not in memory) and return just one of the results using a form with filters.

This is what I have so far but it is all done in memory and not querying the API directly to get the results where "stateCode" is equal to 'DC'

```
<body>

<div ng-form="" ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="customersCtrl">


        <table>
            <tr><td>Filter by First Name:</td><td> <input type="text" ng-model="search.firstName"></td></tr>
            <tr><td>Filter by Last Name:</td><td> <input type="text" ng-model="search.lastName"></td></tr>
            <tr><td>Filter by City:</td><td> <input type="text" ng-model="search.city"></td></tr>
            <tr><td>Filter by State Code:</td><td> <input type="text" ng-model="search.stateCode"></td></tr>
        </table>
        <hr />
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="x in names | filter:search">
            {{ x.firstName + ' ' + x.lastName + ' - ' + x.city + ', ' + x.stateCode }}
        </li>
    </ul>

</div>

<script>
    var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
    app.controller('customersCtrl', function ($scope, $http) {
        $http.get("https://my.ncarb.org/Public/api/certification/search?pageSize=100&page=0&lastName=&firstName=&city=&stateCode=&countryCode=&orderBy=name")
        .success(function (response) { $scope.names = response.data; });
    });
</script>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated to help me with this solution. If you can provide something using JSFiddle, that would be awesome!

Comment: easier to use `params` object in `$http.get` config than manually creating the url query string

Comment: Thanks, I figured it out now. The params idea pointed me to do research in the right direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to craft a solution based on the params advice. I also referenced this thread and built a solution based on one of the answers here: [[Build query string from parameters object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18665850/angularjs-build-url-with-query-string?rq=1][1])