# JSON with PHP Slim and AngularJS

Tags: php, json, angularjs, http

I am trying to send some data from my AngularJS Project to a PHP Server where I am using PHP Slim but I have tried everything I know and nothing seems to work.

SERVER PHP SLIM

```
$app->get('/create',function() use ($app) {

        $data = $app->request()->params();
        response_json(200,"DB: User Created",$data);
});
```

It works if I type directly from the browser

```
http://localhost:8888/core/users/create?login=test&password=123&name=Test&email=test@test.com&phone=12313
```

But if I try to send from the app using $http or $resource

```
var obj = { name:"Hello",email:"hello@email.com"};
$http.get('/core/users/create?',obj).success(function(data){console.log(data); });
```

I get an empty Array[0].

And if I try to use $resource I got an obj but not how I expected.

```
.factory('qServer',function($resource){
return $resource('/core/users/create?:data',{data: '@data'});
});

var obj = { name:"Hello",email:"hello@email.com"};
            var send = JSON.stringify(obj);
            //console.log(lol);
            qServer.get({data:send},function(data) { console.log(data) });
```

With this code I get an Object like that:

```
data: Object
{"name":"Hello","email":"hello@email_com"}: ""
```

Anyone could tell me what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The second argument of [`$http.get`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#get) method is not GET params but a request config.

You want to use something like this (notice the `params` key in config argument and lack of `?` at the end of URL):

```
var obj = { name:"Hello",email:"hello@email.com"};
$http.get('/core/users/create', {params: obj})
.success(function(data){console.log(data); });
```

See also: [Q: $http get parameters does not work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17225088/http-get-parameters-does-not-work) and [config argument docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#usage).

Comment: thanks, I worked it. I thought the usage of the name "params" was optional.